# PeriodicWorkRequest trigger time

Tags: android, job-scheduling, android-workmanager

I wanna add a trigger time to start work on but I can't find a way to do that
with work manger
that's My code

```
 PeriodicWorkRequest alarmWork =
            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                    AlarmWorker.class,
                    interval ,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
            ).setInputData(bundle).build();
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(alarmWork)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to specify exact time at which a Work should be executed. If  you need a task to be executed at exact time regardless of Doze mode, you should use AlarmManager.

However you can setup initial delay with WorkManager as follows:

```
OneTimeWorkRequest mywork=
        new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
        .setInitialDelay(12, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(mywork);
```

Comment: thanks for this solution , i can make OneTimeWorkRequest that execute my PeriodicWorkRequest

Answer (score 0):

The usage is correct; However, I suppose your interval is smaller than [MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest#MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS)

Since the interval must be greater or equal to 15 minutes, PeriodicWorkRequest won't run at the end of the period that you expected.